# MSSQL after insert trigger no working

Tags: sql-server

```
USE [mydatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trgAfterInsert]    Script Date: 14.11.2014 2:30:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[MYTABLE] 
FOR INSERT
AS
        declare @ID int;
        declare @DATE date;
    declare @WHEN smalldatetime;
    declare @WHO NVARCHAR(50);
    declare @WHAT NVARCHAR(max); 
    declare @AUDIT_ACTION varchar(100);


    select @ID        = i.ID from inserted i;   
    select @DATE          = i.DATE from inserted i;
    select @WHEN          = i.WHEN from inserted i;
    select @WHO           = i.WHO from inserted i;
    select @WHAT          = i.WHAT from inserted i;



      UPDATE MYTABLE 
      SET WHEN = GETDATE(),
      WHO      = USER_NAME(USER_ID())
      FROM dbo.MYTABLE  
      INNER JOIN inserted ON MYTABLE.ID = inserted.ID

      insert into AUDIT_LOG           

(DATE,WHEN,WHO,WHAT,USER,AUDIT_ACTION,AUDIT_TIMESTAMP) 
values

(@DATE,@WHEN,@WHO,@WHAT,USER_NAME(USER_ID()),'NEW ENTRY',GETDATE());
```

When run,'when' and 'who' dont get inserted into AUDIT_LOG.

What I am trying to do here is to first update the table and then log
altogether.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think The SQL Editor dealing with the Column 'WHEN' as if it is a reserved keyword, so try to put it between brackets like this [WHEN]